# Corona SDK physics with line, why does the line turn into rectangle in the physics engine?

Tags: sdk, box2d, physics, coronasdk, game-physics

The issue I am having is simple. I have an object in the center of the screen, and then a circle orbiting that object. what i want to do is have the object orbit around the object, when the use touches the screen it will orbit around the object and stop facing where the user tapped the screen.

I am having HUGE amount of difficulty trying to get this work. but what i figured i would do is try to draw a line from the center of the object to where the use clicks and then the ball orbiting the planet hits the line it will stop (simple enough). the problem i am having is that the line object (when viewed in hybrid mode) is more of a rectangle then it is a line (in the physics engine so this messes with my expected result. does anyone have any idea on what im doing wrong here? or how corona is handling this? and how to possibly fix it? or any other solution would work great as well.

```
physics = require("physics") ; physics.start() ; physics.setGravity( 0,0 ) ; 
physics.setDrawMode( "hybrid" )
display.setStatusBar( display.HiddenStatusBar )
math.randomseed( os.time() )


--set up some references and other variables
local ox, oy = math.abs(display.screenOriginX), math.abs(display.screenOriginY)
local cw, ch = display.contentWidth, display.contentHeight

--set up collision filters
local screenFilter = { categoryBits=2, maskBits=1 }
local objFilter = { categoryBits=1, maskBits=14 }
local fieldFilter = { categoryBits=4, maskBits=1 }
local magnetFilter = { categoryBits=8, maskBits=1 }

--set initial magnet pull
local magnetPull = 0.85

--set up world and background
local screenBounds = display.newRect( -ox, -oy, display.contentWidth+ox+ox, display.contentHeight+oy+oy )
screenBounds.name = "screenBounds"
screenBounds.isVisible = false ; physics.addBody( screenBounds, "static", { isSensor=true,     filter=screenFilter } )


local function newPositionVelocity( object )
local math_random = math.random
local side = math_random( 1,4 ) ; local posX ; local posY ; local velX ; local velY

if ( side == 1 or side == 3 ) then
    posX = math_random(0,display.pixelHeight)
    velX = math_random( -10,10 ) * 5
    if ( side == 1 ) then posY = -oy-40 ; velY = math_random( 8,18 ) * 16
    else posY = display.contentHeight+oy+40 ; velY = math_random( 8,16 ) * -16
    end
else
    posY = math_random(0,display.pixelWidth)
    velY = math_random( -10,10 ) * 5
    if ( side == 4 ) then posX = -ox-40 ; velX = math_random( 8,16 ) * 16
    else posX = display.contentWidth+ox+40 ; velX = math_random( 8,16 ) * -16
    end
end
object.x = posX ; object.y = posY
object:setLinearVelocity( velX, velY )
object.angularVelocity = math_random( -3,3 ) * 40
object.alpha = 1

end

require( "repeller");
local rect = createRepeller(15, "rect",cw/2, cw/2);

local function objectCollide( self, event )
local otherName = event.other.name;

local function onDelay( event )
    local action = ""
    if ( event.source ) then action = event.source.action; timer.cancel( event.source ) end

    if ( action == "makeJoint" ) then
        self.hasJoint = true
        self.touchJoint = physics.newJoint( "touch", self, self.x, self.y )
        self.touchJoint.frequency = magnetPull
        self.touchJoint.dampingRatio = 0.0
        self.touchJoint:setTarget( 512, 384 )
    elseif ( action == "leftField" ) then
        self.hasJoint = false ; self.touchJoint:removeSelf() ; self.touchJoint = nil
    else
        if ( self.hasJoint == true ) then self.hasJoint = false ; self.touchJoint:removeSelf() ; self.touchJoint = nil end
        newPositionVelocity( self )
    end
end

if ( event.phase == "ended" and otherName == "screenBounds" ) then
    local tr = timer.performWithDelay( 10, onDelay ) ; tr.action = "leftScreen"
elseif ( event.phase == "began" and otherName == "rect" ) then
    transition.to( self, { time=400, alpha=0, onComplete=onDelay } )
elseif ( event.phase == "began" and otherName == "field" and self.hasJoint == false ) then
    local tr = timer.performWithDelay( 10, onDelay ) ; tr.action = "makeJoint"
elseif ( event.phase == "ended" and otherName == "field" and self.hasJoint == true ) then
    local tr = timer.performWithDelay( 10, onDelay ) ; tr.action = "leftField"
end


end



local function setupWorld()

for i=1, 0 do
    local obj = display.newCircle(0,0, 12 )
    physics.addBody( obj, "dynamic", { bounce=.3, radius=12, density = 0.0 --[[,filter=objFilter]] } )
    obj. isBullet = true;
            newPositionVelocity( obj )
    obj.hasJoint = false;
            obj.name = "ball";
    obj.collision = objectCollide ; obj:addEventListener( "collision", obj )
end

local field = display.newCircle(cw/2, ch/2, 320); 
    field.alpha = 0.2;
field.name = "field";
field.x = display.contentCenterX ; field.y = display.contentCenterY;
physics.addBody( field, "static", { isSensor=true, radius=320, filter=fieldFilter });

magnet = display.newCircle(cw/2, ch/2, 40 )
magnet.name = "magnet"
magnet.x = display.contentCenterX ; magnet.y = display.contentCenterY
physics.addBody( magnet, "static", { bounce=0, radius=40, filter=magnetFilter } )

end

setupWorld()

deg = 0.0;
local prevPosY = 0
local line = display.newLine(cw/2,ch/2,cw/2,ch/2);


local function onTouch(event)
   if line ~= nil then
      line:removeSelf();
   end

   if event.phase == "began" then
      prevPosY = event.y
   end

   if(event.y >= prevPosY) then
      myJoint.motorSpeed = -(1.5 * prevPosY - event.y);
   elseif(event.y <= prevPosY) then
      myJoint.motorSpeed =   1.5 * prevPosY - event.y;
   end  

   if(prevPosY - event.y == 0) then
      --myJoint.motorSpeed = 0;
   end
   prevPosY = event.y;
   line = display.newLine(cw/2,ch/2,event.x, event.y);
   line.width= 1;
   line.name = "line";
   physics.addBody(line, { isSensor = true })
   local function lineCol(self, event)
     if (event.other.name=="rect") then
        myJoint.motorSpeed = 0;
        print(event.other.name, event.name);
        --rect:removeSelf();
     end
   end
   line.collision = lineCol;
   line:addEventListener("collision", line); 
end
   line = display.newLine(cw/2,ch/2, 200 , 250);
   line.width= 1;
   line.name = "line";
   physics.addBody(line, { isSensor = true, shape=line })
--Runtime:addEventListener( "collision", lineCol)
physics.addBody(rect,"dynamic", {bounce = 0, density = 0})

myJoint = physics.newJoint( "pivot", rect, magnet, cw/2, ch/2);
myJoint.isMotorEnabled = true;
myJoint.motorSpeed = 0;
myJoint.maxMotorTorque = 100;

Runtime:addEventListener("touch", onTouch);
```

and my "repeller.lua"

```
function createRepeller(size, name, locX, locY)
   local rep = display.newCircle(locX,locY, size);
   rep.name = name;
   return rep;
end
```

Comment: please leave only problem related code

Comment: Im not sure i understand. I am having a problem with my code. I surely hope you do not mean syntax errors? The issue with my problem is, i do not fully understand where my problem is or where to even begin solving.

Comment: Do you really need to use physics? Because I dont think physics is necessary here. With simple math, positions of objects and rotation values of objects you can achieve what you want. I suggest you to change your algorithm into this way. And also you can use math.atan functions for such a thing.

Comment: Btw I created something like that with simple math, positions of objects and rotation values. There were some cannons, aiming to enemies automaticaly. Everything worked great, without physics.

Answer (score 0):

In Corona, lines aren't really applicable for physics bodies... as in, you can apply one, but it probably won't be the shape you expect. What I would advise is to create a very thin rectangle (a newRect()) object and then rotate/position that line to the point where you need. Or, just use math formulas like the other user suggests.

Best of luck,
Brent